# constant time complexity: O(x^c)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I know if we use constant number of operation our `time complexity` is `constant`.

so what if we have following scenario:

for example an operation uses an array of fixed size `1000`. no matter what that operation or what size of the input is the amount of computation will always be `(1000 ^ 1000)` (the computation is regardless of the size of input)

can we still say that its time complexity still `O(1)` , even our number of operation is `(1000^1000)`?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. As N increases, the computation time stays constant. When doing asymptotic analysis, the value of that constant does not matter.

Comment: By the way, what else could it be ?

Comment: then isn't "asymptotic analysis" is a weak approach to do analysis? i mean it doesn't truly explain how long an operation should take.

Comment: Asymptotic analysis is a fundamental and extremely powerful tool. One of its assets is "programming language/programmer skills/hardware-independence", which makes is such that the results obtained will remain true for the next millennium, whereas actual running times change every day. Also, very importantly: it gives you insight on what the algorithm is doing and if it can be improved. Raw numbers are of no use.

Comment: @nafas It's good enough in practice, but it's not ideal. See the concept of galactic algorithms for example. There are also approaches which give better estimates of running time of algorithms (e.g. analytic combinatorics, etc.)

Comment: Actually, asymptotic analysis is much more *accurate* than empirical measurement. It gives you a trend in analytical form with an indication of the influencing factors and is predictive, whereas program benchmarking, on modern machines, gives you figures with a very high dispersion (the variation coefficient that can exceed 100%).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so.

Complexity is mainly used to indicate the order of growth of your algorithms. That is, how you algorithm will scale if the input is increased.
Now, given that the space and time used by your algorithm are constant regardless of the input, we can say that it has constant space or time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any constant. That "big O" thing is a set of functions, following this definition

```
f(x) ϵ O(g(x)) <-> ∃m,c ∀n≥m f(n) ≤ c g(x)
```

As you can see here, you may simply pick `c` as your huge constant, and thereby put it in the class O(1).

That should not be taken as a statement about real life performance, for obvious reasons.